# Play a sound on button click before loading the load scene in Unity3D

Tags: unity, c#, sound, sound-effects

I am trying to play the sound of the button click before loading the scene in unity. However, the sound is never played. Below is my code, help would be appreciated.

```
public void RestartGame()
{
    audioManager.PlaySound(forwardSound);
    StartCoroutine(DelaySceneLoad("Gameplay"));
}

IEnumerator DelaySceneLoad(string scene)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(forwardSound.length);
    GameTracker.SetGameOver(false);
    SceneManager.LoadScene(scene);
}
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. Do you get any errors from the PlaySound line? Have you ensured your sound is pre-loaded so it's not delayed by streaming from disc? Can your show us the relevant `audioManager` code so we can check for errors there?

Answer (score 2):

[`SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync()` might be of interest to you,](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync.html) it lets you do lots of cool things such as loading screens and more before a scene completes loading and changes.

Instead of waiting for the length of your audio clip (which might not be loaded and played completely from memory in time), try checking to see if the `AudioSource` its attached to `isPlaying` and load the scene when it sets to `false`.